# javascript in mozilla firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, function, mozilla

how to implement javascript in mozilla firefox addons development?
whether different ways to implement javascript in mozilla firefox with javascript in general?

for example if I want to create a function like this:

```
function selectedText () {
var userSelection;
   if (window.getSelection) {
      userSelection = window.getSelection();
   } else if (document.selection) {
       userSelection = document.selection.createRange();
   }
   return userSelection;
}
```

whether the same function if I write the function like this:

```
  selectedText : function () {
    var userSelection;
       if (window.getSelection) {
          userSelection = window.getSelection();
       } else if (document.selection) {
           userSelection = document.selection.createRange();
       }
       return userSelection;
    },
```

Comment: whatever you do, you don't need the else-branch you actually use there, because this branch is related to internet-explorer.

Comment: so,whether the way to implementation of javascript in firefox actually same with javascript in general?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both these methods can be used to define functions/methods in javascript. It is not specific to developing firefox extensions. You can put any legitimate javascript code in your firefox extension script file.

Comment: so I can use javascript with any method in developing mozilla?

Comment: if you mean, you can use either of the two ways, Yes.

Comment: one question for you, is it true if i want to execute function in another function i just execute like this getSelected(); in both of them? or any different way to execute?